# SpringBootData ElasticSearch cannot create index on non-indexed field

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm struggling creating a Document with field that are specified to be analyzed by ElasticSearch. I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch version 4.1.6.

This is my Entity

```java
@Document(indexName = "employee-info")
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EmployeeInfo {
    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String empNo;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String pinCd;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String empNm;
    @Field(index = false)
    private String fullDeptCd;//00082;N0001;N0002;N0060;LW00002289;LW00002384;LW00002501",

    // ... other fields

}
```

Upon Bootstrapping, it logs:

```
2022-03-09 13:03:22,477 WARN  [main] SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:96: Cannot create index: Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=No type specified for field [fullDeptCd]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=No type specified for field [fullDeptCd]]]
```

and the mapping:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "empNo": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "fullDeptCd": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        ...
```

- Why `empNo` is `text` but its `fields` are `keyword` and it also doesn't have `index`?
- Why `fullDeptCd` mapping is exactly the same as `empNo`?

What I understand:

- `FieldType.Keyword`: this field will not be tokenized, but it is still indexed by default.
- `FieldType.Text`: this field will be tokenized by the analyzer.
- `index = false`: do not analyzed and index this field.

I feel like it's very difficult to work with ElasticSearch with SpringBoot, a lot of property in @Field annotation are not documented and I don't know how to use them properly.

If you have experience with ElasticSearch, please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for some reason, the default `FieldType.Auto` not working, I have to explicitly specify type for all fields.